# Either content or contents 161

Tags: nouns

In the following sentence

> I read the letter and made him aware of its **content/contents**

Which one should be used? Either content or contents.

To me **content** seems a proper choice. But in my book it is **contents**.

Comment: I think that you have accepted the first answer too quickly. I have been looking in the Cambridge Dictionary and I haven't answered because I have found two contradictory definitions there for content/contents. One of them with this example: "He didn't need to open the letter because he already knew the contents." A letter and its contents, just like your example. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/content

Comment: What kind of book did you see this in, and what specifically does that book say?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Content is the correct answer here. This is because 'content' in this case is an uncountable noun, because it is a collection of words that cannot be measured. If, however, you were talking about something that could be measured, such as the contents of a cake, you would use contents because this is a countable noun and we can weigh the contents of the cake.

Comment: According to the Cambridge Dictionary, you can consider a letter as a container, and everything contained in it as its contents: "He didn't need to open the letter because he already knew the contents"  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/content

Comment: I think both are correct, it depends on how we use it